# Use of numpy fromfunction

Tags: python, numpy, lambda

im trying to use fromfunction to create a 5x5 matrix with gaussian values of mu=3 and sig=2, this is my attempt :

```
from random import gauss
import numpy as np
np.fromfunction(lambda i,j: gauss(3,2), (5, 5))
```

this is the result : 5.365244570434782

as i understand from the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfunction.html) this should have worked, but i am getting a scalar instead of 5x5 matrix... why? and how to fix this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `numpy.fromfunction` docs are extremely misleading. Instead of calling your function repeatedly and building an array from the results, `fromfunction` actually only makes one call to the function you pass it. In that one call, it passes a number of index arrays to your function, instead of individual indices.

Stripping out the docstring, the implementation is as follows:

```
def fromfunction(function, shape, **kwargs):
    dtype = kwargs.pop('dtype', float)
    args = indices(shape, dtype=dtype)
    return function(*args,**kwargs)
```

That means unless your function broadcasts, `numpy.fromfunction` doesn't do anything like what the docs say it does.

Comment: So how would you use fromfunction in my use case?

Comment: @OfekRon I don't know. However, I believe `numpy` has a `random` module that should already provide the ability to create arrays with elements from gaussian distributions etc...

Comment: @Bakuriu can you be more specific?

Comment: @OfekRon: I wouldn't. I'd use [`numpy.random.normal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html) instead of `random.gauss`.

Comment: @user2357112 np.random.normal(3,2,(5,5)) works great!, wonder why gauss function exists but oh well

Comment: @OfekRon That would be because python's `random` module is different from numpy's `random` module.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but for anyone stumbling upon this, the reason why it didn't work is, the expression inside `lambda` is not making use of the `i, j` variables

what you need could you achieved like this:

```
np.zeros((5, 5)) + gauss(3, 2)
```