# numpy array fromfunction using each previous value as input, with non-zero initial value

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy

I would like to fill a numpy array with values using a function. I want the array to start with one initial value and be filled to a given length, using each previous value in the array as the input to the function.

Each array value i should be (i-1)*x**(y/z).

After a bit of work, I have got to:

```
import numpy as np
f = np.zeros([31,1])
f[0] = 20
fun = lambda i, j: i*2**(1/3)
f[1:] = np.fromfunction(np.vectorize(fun), (len(f)-1,1), dtype = int)
```

This fills an array with

[firstvalue=20, 0, i-1 + 1*2**(1/3),...]

I have arrived here having read

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.fromfunction.html

[Use of numpy fromfunction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40672367/use-of-numpy-fromfunction)

[Most efficient way to map function over numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215161/most-efficient-way-to-map-function-over-numpy-array)

[Fastest way to populate a matrix with a function on pairs of elements in two numpy vectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26671931/fastest-way-to-populate-a-matrix-with-a-function-on-pairs-of-elements-in-two-num)

[How do I create a numpy array using a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16800355/how-do-i-create-a-numpy-array-using-a-function)

But I'm just not getting how to translate it to my function.

Comment: Show us how you would do this calculation with iteration.  As my answer shows (and your links) `fromfunction` does not help you do iterative code.  It just applies the function to the whole set of indices (with 1 call).  `vectorize` also isn't helpful.  It's just a convenient way of broadcasting multiple arrays to a function that only takes scalars.  Neither of these promise speed.

Comment: Thanks, I realised when I woke up today that it's impossible to vectorise this type of operation, as it would violate causality; the function cannot know what the i-1th value is until it has already calculated it, so it must be a series (iterative) operation to calculate the next value of i. I feel very stupid. I will have a go at iterating it and repost.

Comment: `for i in np.linspace(1,len(f)-1,len(f)-1, dtype=int):
    f[i] = f[i-1]*2**(1/3)`

Comment: Doesn't seem very pythonic, more matlabby, but that's where I'm coming from...

Comment: Iteration is very pythonic; that's how lists are processed all the time.  MATLAB used to require 'vectorization' in the same sense as `numpy`; but they've since added `jit` compilation, that reduces the need to think in terms of whole arrays.  ``numba` and `cython` can be used to the same effect.

Comment: See my edits for a `cumprod` solution.

Comment: Very helpful and thorough answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except for the initial 20, this produces the same values

```
np.arange(31)*2**(1/3)
```

---

Your iterative version (slightly modified)

```
def foo0(n):
    f = np.zeros(n)
    f[0] = 20
    for i in range(1,n): 
        f[i] = f[i-1]*2**(1/3)
    return f
```

An alternative:

```
def foo1(n):
    g = [20]
    for i in range(n-1):
        g.append(g[-1]*2**(1/3))
    return np.array(g)
```

They produce the same thing:

```
In [25]: np.allclose(foo0(31), foo1(31))
Out[25]: True
```

Mine is a bit faster:

```
In [26]: timeit foo0(100)
35 µs ± 75 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [27]: timeit foo1(100)
23.6 µs ± 83.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

But we don't need to evaluate `2**(1/3)` every time

```
def foo2(n):
    g = [20]
    const = 2**(1/3)
    for i in range(n-1):
        g.append(g[-1]*const)
    return np.array(g)
```

minor time savings.  But that's just multiplying each entry by the same const.  So we can use `cumprod` for a bigger time savings:

```
def foo3(n):
    g = np.ones(n)*(2**(1/3))
    g[0]=20
    return np.cumprod(g)

In [37]: timeit foo3(31)
14.9 µs ± 14.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [40]: np.allclose(foo0(31), foo3(31))
Out[40]: True
```

Comment: Thankyou, but even if the first value was 20, this doesn't use the i-1th value to calculate i.