# Double for loop vs np.fromfunction(), why do they give different result in my case?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

while trying to program something I've come to need to create a 2D array(matrix) from a function that takes matrix indices (i and j in below example) as arguments and returns the matrix element.

I've seen from other answers that numpy.fromfunction() along with numpy.vectorize() should do the trick, however in my case those two seem to give a different result, what could be wrong?

More specifically I am comparing this:

```
for i in range(velikost):
    for j in range(velikost):
        u[i][j] = pomozna(i,j)
return u
```

to this(which I thought is equivalent to the above):

```
return np.fromfunction(np.vectorize(pomozna),u.shape)
```

Below is my full code, if you wish to run it by yourself. Any help appreciated, thanks!

```
import numpy as np
def jacobi(u,h,q):
    velikost = u[0].size
    star = np.copy(u)
    def pomozna(i,j):
        if i==0 or i==velikost-1 or j==0 or j==velikost-1:
            return 0
        return 1/4*(star[int(i+1)][int(j)]+star[int(i-1)][int(j)]+star[int(i)][int(j+1)]+star[int(i)][int(j-1)] - h*h*q[int(i)][int(j)])
    #return np.fromfunction(np.vectorize(pomozna),u.shape)
    for i in range(velikost):
        for j in range(velikost):
            u[i][j] = pomozna(i,j)
    return u
h=0.05
iksi = np.linspace(0,1,int(1/h))
ipsiloni = np.linspace(0,1,int(1/h))
qji = [[-1 for iks in iksi] for ips in ipsiloni]
zacetna = np.asarray([[1.0 for iks in iksi] for ips in ipsiloni])
zacetna[0] = np.zeros(iksi.size)
zacetna[-1]=np.zeros(iksi.size)
zacetna[:,0] = np.zeros(iksi.size)
zacetna[:,-1] = np.zeros(iksi.size)
print(jacobi(zacetna,h,qji))
```

Comment: Can you provide the output you get in both cases?

Comment: Sure, https://pastebin.com/YPGWDszc

Comment: You start with an array of `1`s. While the for-loop takes previously calculated values into account, the vectorized approach sees the array of `1`s all the time and since 1/4*(1+1+1+1) == 1, the result is an array of all ones (except where you set it to `0`.

Comment: Where did you see that `fromfunction` can be used this way?  I just showed that it isn't useful, [numpy array fromfunction using each previous value as input, with non-zero initial value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49434319)

Comment: The for loop shouldn't take previously calculated values into account, that's why I made a copy of my array at start(start=np.copy(u)) Or do changes in my copy also make changes in my original array?

Comment: I was referring to this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18702105/parameters-to-numpys-fromfunction , found one more but can't find it right now.

Comment: You need to initialize `u` to dtype `int` in the first case.

Comment: Why would I need to initialize u to dtype int? I don't want to limit my outputs to ints, I want to allow them to be floats, which is what they should be(The code is part of some differential equation solver I am trying to make)

Comment: Found the answer, the problem was indeed with some sort of integer interpretation, changing the "return 0" to "return 0.0" fixed the problem :)

Comment: `vectorize` chooses the return dtype based on an initial test calculation.  If it returned 0, the dtype was 0.  A way around this is to use `otypes` parameter.

Comment: But you were right in your answer, fromfunction is actually pretty slow. Thanks for that info and all the help :)

Comment: Experiment with an expression like `u[1:,:]+u[:-1,:]+u[:,1:]+u[:,:-1]` instead of the `i,j` iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps try

```
return 0.0
```

in pomozna.